# Problema con .htaccess ErrorDocument

Tags: .htaccess

Tengo una página de 404.php y la intención es que mediante .htaccess te lleve a esa página en caso de error 404, pero no funciona.

Este es el archivo htacccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
```

Este es el error que me da:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /CBS/CBSLanguageAcademy/hi was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

No sé porque me da ese error, soy bastante malo con el .htaccess.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problema resuelto**

En el .htaccess tienes que especificar la ruta exacta desde donde se encuentra el index principal del dominio. Es decir, yo tengo esta estructura:

wwww.unaprueba.com/enlaces/paginas/index.php

Si el archivo .htaccess esta donde se encuentra el Index.php de la carpeta paginas, no sirve con poner solamente:

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Tendrías que poner:

ErrorDocument 404 /enlaces/paginas/404.php

Espero que me haya explicado correctamente.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

Ponlo de este modo

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

Comment: Agrega una explicaciónde esto por favor. Revisar [answer]